# Flutter how to show more replies

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to add a show replies button like instagram in a flutter app but i don't know how to do it and how to calculate the height after in order to show the comments.
the result that im trying to achieve is like
[this picutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8mKP.jpg)

all help is appriciated

Comment: Please share the code you tried so far. In general you would have to get the list of replies's length. And for the height of the container, use a listview builder, and it'll take car of that.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad sorry im really new to flutter and i don't know where or how to start

Comment: first question , do you have a list of all replies?

Comment: @griffins I have a list of all parent comments and when someone clicks on show replies i will fetch every child of that parent comment and show it but since theres no character limit theres no way to know the height of the comments

Comment: well , you can check the length of the list, if greater than 2, show the show more

Comment: @griffins i don't know how to expand the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a state so when the text is taped you could show the list and it will expand automatically

```
Column(
   children: [
      CommentWidget(),
      MoreCommentWidget(),
      AnotherComment()
   ]
)
```

MoreCommentWidget:

```
class MoreCommentWidget extends StatefulWidget {

MoreCommentWidget({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _MoreCommentWidgetState createState() => _MoreCommentWidgetState();
}

class _MoreCommentWidgetState extends State<MoreCommentWidget> {
  bool showList = false;

  List<String> comments = List.generate(10, (index) => "comment $index");

  void expandList(){
    setState(() {
      showList = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(showList)
      return Container(height: 200, width: 60,child: ListView.builder(itemCount: comments.length,itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(height: 40, width: 60, child: Text("${comments[index]}"),)));
    else
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          expandList();
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Text("Show More..."),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```